# Jar can not resolve org.apache.commons import

Tags: java, jar

I am not particularly well experienced with Java at all and try to get a jar file running on my Ubuntu machine (https://sites.google.com/site/communitydetectionslpa/home).

However once I run the jar file with the command suggested by developers I receive the following error:

```
java -jar GANXiSw.jar -i test.ipairs 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiKeyMap
    at Net.<init>(Net.java:38)
    at SLPAw.<init>(SLPAw.java:146)
    at SLPAw.main(SLPAw.java:2050)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiKeyMap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

Apparently java is not able to import the org.apache.commons class properly. After some researching I checked if I have `libcommons-collections3-java` installed, which however is the case.
I read something about adding the library explicitly to my `CLASSPATH`, which however I also read to be not good practice.

What is the best approach to fix my issue?

Comment: add your jar to your classpath

Comment: Use maven to create a simple java project, and maven will pack all your project in a jar will all needed jars, later you can run the final project.jar

Comment: Adding the jar to the classpath EXPORT classpath="/my/path/.../GANXiSw.jar"  did not work. Also I can not use maven since it is not my java project, but rather was developed by someone else. I just want to get it running on my machine.